# What is the proper way to add a reference to Android Studio v0.8.10

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to add the GooglePlayServices SDK to a project following the directions [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html), however these instructions are specific to Eclipse. I have also found IntellJ instructions that are similar however not close enough.

Is there are quick tutorial specific to this version (yes I have looked)?

Thanks

EDIT: 
I apologise that I was so vague in my question but I literally had to get this asked before going to a meeting. The reason I suspected that Google Play Services wasn't in Android Studio is because when I push the project to an emulator I get the following error:

```
Google Play Store is missing. 
I/myLogs﹕ No valid Google Play Services APK found.
```

Is there something I can do to push the APK to the device?

Answer (score 1):

To add GooglePlayServices to Android Studio, just use [this page](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup) and select "Using Android Studio" from the dropdown. Start by adding the gradle dependency.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
}
```

Then add this to your manifest.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I apologise that I was so vague in my question but I literally had to get this asked before going to a meeting. The reason I suspected that Google Play Services wasn't in Android Studio is because when I push the project to an emulator I get the following error:Google Play Store is missing.
I/myLogs﹕ No valid Google Play Services APK found. Is there something I can do to push the APK to the device?

Comment: Use the Google API system image instead of just the Android one.